# Rtmp files remain in tmpdir after using vscode R extension

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm using the R extension version v2.8.0, to edit and run an R script (R v4.1.0) from a remote server (Centos-7) using the vscode remote development pack (v0.24.0).

If I quit the R session using quit(), the Rtmp folders in tmp are removed, however if my ssh connection fails or I simply close the window with the script in it, the Rtmp files hang around until I manually delete them. This isn't a huge problem but I find it annoying and I'm wondering if a) this is expected and b) if there's a simple solution to prevent the accumulation of 100's of Rtmps in my tmp directory and automatically delete them when I close vscode, for example.

This problem is not replicated if I run the script using "Rscript myscript.R", but I would still prefer to use R interactively.

Comment: why not create an issue at the extension repo that creates these files